# Wordpress Body Content How to add current page title automatically in different places?

Tags: automation, wp-title

I'm new to wordpress with very limited/low knowledge in coding,

I'm trying to build a faq section for different pages, where I need to insert the page title, post date, author etc. in multiple places. I want this below the content in many pages,

Eg.

1.How do i use (page title)
A.Use this (page title) as instructed here (link) by (author)
2.Where do i buy (page title)
A.Buy (page title) from here (link).

How do I accomplish this?

Is this possible using the wordpress editor?

Thank you

Comment: Many of the answers you're looking for can be found by studying the WordPress functions list: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/

Comment: Thanks. I completed the first part, For anyone looking for the same,

I stumbled on PHP code snippets and used that and created a shortcode with php with <?php wp_title(); ?> to show what I wanted in my faq sections,

Now need some help in showing this faq to all my posts under one category.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

In order to programmatically print the page title, use `<?php the_title(); ?>`. [More here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/).

The other programmatic functions can be found in the [WP functions library](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/).